# Linker Command Failed Error, Tried Everything

Tags: xcode9

I've tried everything and it keeps giving me the same error. Not sure how to solve this.

Here is the error.
[image: Figure 1]

After setting it to 'fast whole', I'm getting this error.
[image: Figure 2]

I've tried deleting Derived Data, setting 'No Common Blocks' to NO, setting 'Enable Testability' to NO and setting 'Optimization' to fast whole (all from resources I found on StackOverFlow). Nothing works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually didn't import my OBJC files properly. Once I did this, all seemed to be fine.